# Replacing composed functions in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to generate some random expressions in the form `f(g(x))`. I'd like to be able to replace `g` with something like `sin(x)` or `x**2` and `f` with something like `cos(x)` or `log(x)`. So I'd get something like `sin(cos(x))` or `log(x**2)` (but randomized).

The part of this task I'm having trouble with is replacing both an outer and inner function.

Here's my code:

```
import sympy
from sympy import abc

x = abc.x
f = sympy.Function('f')(x)
g = sympy.Function('g')(x)

full=f.subs(x, g)
newExpr = sympy.sin(x)
newExpr2 = sympy.cos(x)

print(full)

replaced_inner = full.subs(g, newExpr)
print(replaced_inner)

both = replaced_inner.subs(f, newExpr2)
print(both)
```

`full` prints `f(g(x))` so that works
`replaced_inner` prints `f(sin(x))` so that works as well
`both` prints `f(sin(x))` when I want it to print `cos(sin(x))`

I've tried using `args[0]` and `f.func` but haven't made progress.

How can I replace both the inner and outer functions (and eventually more complex things like `f(g(h(x)))`.

I could simply create `cos(sin(x))` but I want to do it using variables so I can randomize what function gets replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in confusion of **functions** like `sympy.Function('f')` and **expressions** like `sympy.Function('f')(x)`. Having defined `f = sympy.Function('f')(x)` you made `f` the expression `f(x)`. And since
the expression `f(g(x))` does not have `f(x)` as a subexpression, attempted substitution fails.

All this is fixed if you work with actual functions, not plugging `x` in prematurely.

```
f = sympy.Function('f')
g = sympy.Function('g')

full = f(g(x))
newExpr = sympy.sin
newExpr2 = sympy.cos

print(full)

replaced_inner = full.subs(g, newExpr)
print(replaced_inner)

both = replaced_inner.subs(f, newExpr2)
print(both)
```

This prints

```
f(g(x))
f(sin(x))
cos(sin(x))
```

Aside: you may also be interested in [`replace`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) method which supports certain patterns. Not necessary here, but may be necessary for more advanced replacements.